# Nested requestAnimationFrame calls - order of repaints and callback invocations

Tags: javascript, webapi, requestanimationframe

I am trying to understand how requestAnimationFrame works, so that I know exactly what behavior to expect when I use it. From what I understand, when I call requestAnimationFrame, it "tells" the browser that I want to call the function I passed to it as an argument sometime before the next repaint. I expect that this function will *definitely be called* before the next repaint, whenever that is. I do not expect that the repaint will necessarily happen *immediately* after my function is called.

Say I have something like:

```
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    do_1st_thing();
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        do_2nd_thing();
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {
            do_3rd_thing();
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                do_4th_thing();
                requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                    do_5th_thing();
                })
            })
        })
    })
});
```

I assume that *generally* something like this will happen, in this order:

```
1st thing
repaint
2nd thing
repaint
3rd thing
repaint
4th thing 
repaint
5th thing
repaint
```

I assume something like this *could* also happen:

```
1st thing
2nd thing
repaint
3rd thing
4th thing 
repaint
5th thing
repaint
```

But generally I expect that there will be repaints between thing 1, thing 2, thing 3 and so on.

Where it gets confusing for me is that I don't know *why* this is the case. Based on my understanding so far, it "should" go something like this: the browser is about to do a repaint. At some point the outermost rAF call happened, so it knows that it needs to do thing 1 AND call rAF again before it can do the repaint. So, it does thing 1, calls rAF, at which point it is told that before the next repaint, there is more stuff to be done (thing 2, and another rAF call).
Now, does it decide to go ahead with the repaint and...queue thing 2 & the next rAF call for before the *repaint after the one it was about to do*, or does it ...just do them immediately*? I assume not, but I'm not sure why, other than it would be silly.

My second question is, assuming there's repaints between thing 1, thing 2, thing 3 and so on: Is there any guarantee that there will *always* be a repaint between them?

*ultimately leading to this order:

```
thing 1
thing 2
thing 3
thing 4
thing 5
repaint
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser has to maintain an *ordered [map of animation frame callbacks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#list-of-animation-frame-callbacks)*.
When you call `requestAnimationFrame(cb)`, `cb` is queued in that map.
In the *rendering frame*, which is a special iteration of the event-loop where the browser will run until the end of the ["update the rendering"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#update-the-rendering) steps, the browser will run a few event callbacks like `resize`, or `scroll`, etc., and then it will *[run the animation frame callbacks](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/imagebitmap-and-animations.html#run-the-animation-frame-callbacks)*. This algorithm basically ask to grab all the keys currently in the *animation frame callbacks queue*, and iterate over that list of keys and callbacks without looking back at the map. So if new callbacks are added during this algorithm, they won't be called right now, but only the next time this algorithm is executed.

In pseudo code that would give

```
while(true) {
  // Do all the thing the event loop has to do, like pick a task to run
  ...
  if (now() === time_to_render) { // "rendering frame"
    runAllTheRenderRelatedEventCallbacks();
    // run the animation frame callbacks
    let keys = getKeys(animationFrameCallbacksMap);
    for(let key of keys) {
      let callback = animationFrameCallbacksMap[key];
      delete animationFrameCallbacksMap[key]; // remove from the map
      call(callback); // Even if here we add a new rAF callback to the map,
                      // its key won't be in 'keys' yet
    }
    doOtherStuffLikeRunTheResizeObserverCallbacks();
    paint();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you request for animation frame you tell the browser to run this callback function before your repaint!

So every inner request will queue before next paint and the run step will happen on next render!

Thus the order will preserve and there is a guarantee that there will be a repaint between them!

Now you know that you should know there is no nested calling! Stack is always one level! Because the function `requestAnimationFrame()` is just some kind of promise. Function executer will be the main thread! This function just puts the call back in queue.

Comment: "there is a guarantee that there will be a repaint between them" - do you have a source for this?

Comment: I've found this on MDN about RAF: "Note: Your callback routine must itself call requestAnimationFrame() again if you want to animate another frame at the next repaint." - it implies that the call inside callback routine will be called at next RAF queue polling